# Problem connectiong to a SQL Server 2008 named instance using Hibernate

Tags: sql-server-2005, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using Hibernate to connect to an SQL Server 2008 named instance.

This works if I use the default instance name but not when using the "named" instance.

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\INSTANCE_NAME:1433;databaseName=DB_NAME;autoReconnect=true");
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A named instance does not listen on port 1433, only the default instance

You should not need the `:1433` bit

Default vs named instances is mentioned in the [MS JDBC info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx)